# Javascript appended data not working function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry my bad English ı append new data using ajax like this

```
<span class="commentbuton" id="143">Comment..</span>
```

and javascript is

```
$(function(){
    $(".commentbuton").click(function() { ...
```

but its not working on new appended data please help thanks.

Comment: ok thanks ı solved Do I need to delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the click listener after the element is inserted into the page. My guess is that you bind the click handler before the existance of ".commentbutton".

```
$('body').html('<div class="commentbutton"></div>')
//bind after commentbutton inserted
$(".commentbuton").click(function() { ... });
```

Does this help?

Comment: $(document).on("click", '.classname',function() {
ı solved like this thanks..